# UriTemplate matching with optional trailing slash

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url-mapping, url-pattern

I'm using the Spring Web `UriTemplate` for some URL matching. In the following example, the second assert fails because of the mismatched slash at the end of the URL:

```
UriTemplate uriTemplate = new UriTemplate("/myservice/{version}/stuff");

String inputUriA = "/myservice/v1/stuff"; // Without slash
assertTrue(uriTemplate.matches(inputUriA)); // Matches

String inputUriB = "/myservice/v1/stuff/"; // With slash
assertTrue(uriTemplate.matches(inputUriB)); // Does not match
```

I'm aware that the two cases (with slash and without) technically resolve to two separate REST resources. However, in common use, these URLs are generally considered equivalent. Is there a way to configure the `uriTemplate` to match both `inputUriA` and `inputUriB`?

I'm using Spring Web 4.0.8.RELEASE.

Comment: I don't think there is.